# Value not loaded into JSF form for editing

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

index.xhtml

This page lists the product information where user can edit or delete products. When I click on edit link, the page gets redirected to editProduct.xhtml but the values are not loaded on the form. An empty form gets loaded. Values for selected productId gets printed in netbeans console but not in the jsf form.

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
                <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                      xmlns:fcore="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
                    <h:head>
                        <title>Product </title>
                    </h:head>
                    <h:body>

                        <br/>

                        <center>
                            <h2> Product Lists</h2>
                            <fcore:view>
                                <h:form>
                                    <h:dataTable var="lists" value="#{productController.getAllProduct()}" border="1" cellpadding="10">
                                        <h:column>
                                            <fcore:facet name="header">Product Id</fcore:facet>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{lists.productId}" />
                                        </h:column>

                                        <h:column>
                                            <fcore:facet name="header">Product Name</fcore:facet>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{lists.productName}" />
                                        </h:column>

                                        <h:column>
                                            <fcore:facet name="header">Product Price</fcore:facet>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{lists.productPrice}" />
                                        </h:column>

                                        <h:column>
                                            <fcore:facet name="header">Product Quantity</fcore:facet>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{lists.productQty}" />
                                        </h:column>

                                        <h:column>
                                            <fcore:facet name="header">Product Description</fcore:facet>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{lists.productDesc}" />
                                        </h:column>

                                        <h:column>
                                            <fcore:facet name="header">Purchase Date</fcore:facet>
                                            <h:outputText value="#{lists.purchaseDate}" />
                                        </h:column>

                                        <h:column>

                                            <fcore:facet name="header">Edit</fcore:facet>
                                            <h:commandLink action="editProduct" actionListener="#{productController.findProductById(lists.productId)}" value="Edit">
                                                <fcore:param name="id" value="#{lists.productId}"/>
                                            </h:commandLink>

                                        </h:column>

                                        <h:column>

                                            <fcore:facet name="header">Delete</fcore:facet>
                                            <h:commandLink action="index" actionListener="#{productController.deleteCategory(lists.productId)}" onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure ?')" value="Delete">
                                                <fcore:param name="id" value="#{lists.productId}"/>
                                            </h:commandLink>

                                        </h:column>

                                    </h:dataTable>

                                    <h:commandLink value="Add New Product" action="addProduct" />
                                </h:form>
                            </fcore:view>
                        </center>
                    </h:body>
                </html>
```

here is the java bean along with getters and setters.

ProductManagedBean.java

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class ProductManagedBean {

        private int productId;
        private String productName;
        private double productPrice;
        private int productQty;
        private String productDesc;
        private Date purchaseDate;

        //getters and setter here ...
    }
```

here is the controller for fetching the values. The selected productId's value gets printed in console but not in the jsf form.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "productController")
public class ProductController  {
    public ProductManagedBean findProductById(int productId) {
        ProductManagedBean productManagedBean = new ProductManagedBean();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE proId = ?";

        try {
            DbConnection.DbDriver();
            pstat = DbConnection.con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstat.setInt(1, productId);

            resultSet = pstat.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("\n--- Product Id = " + productId);

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                productManagedBean.setProductId(resultSet.getInt("proId"));
                productManagedBean.setProductName(resultSet.getString("proName"));
                productManagedBean.setProductPrice(resultSet.getDouble("proPrice"));
                productManagedBean.setProductQty(resultSet.getInt("proQty"));
                productManagedBean.setProductDesc(resultSet.getString("proDesc"));
                productManagedBean.setPurchaseDate(resultSet.getDate("proDate"));

                System.out.println(productManagedBean.getProductId() + "\t" + productManagedBean.getProductName()
                        + "\t" + productManagedBean.getProductPrice() + "\t" + productManagedBean.getProductQty()
                        + "\t" + productManagedBean.getProductDesc() + "\t" + productManagedBean.getPurchaseDate());
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProductController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

  public void update(ProductManagedBean productManagedBean) {

  String query = "UPDATE product SET proName = ?, proPrice = ?, proQty = ?, proDesc = ?, proDate = ? "
            + "WHERE proId = ?";

    try {
        DbConnection.DbDriver();
        pstat = DbConnection.con.prepareStatement(query);

        pstat.setString(1, productManagedBean.getProductName());
        pstat.setDouble(2, productManagedBean.getProductPrice());
        pstat.setInt(3, productManagedBean.getProductQty());
        pstat.setString(4, productManagedBean.getProductDesc());
        pstat.setDate(5, new Date(productManagedBean.getPurchaseDate().getTime()));
        pstat.setInt(6, productManagedBean.getProductId());

        int save = pstat.executeUpdate();
        if (save > 0) {
            System.out.println("\n\n---- New Product Saved ---- " + productManagedBean.getProductName() + " --- \n");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProductController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   }
}
```

here is the editProduct.xhtml page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"               "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:fcore="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Update Product</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <center>
        <fcore:view>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid border="1" cellpadding="10" columns="2">

                    <h:outputLabel value="Product Id"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{productManagedBean.productId}" >                            
                    </h:inputText>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Product Name"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{productManagedBean.productName}" required="true">                            
                    </h:inputText>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Product Price"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{productManagedBean.productPrice}" required="true">                            
                    </h:inputText>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Product Qty"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{productManagedBean.productQty}" required="true">                            
                    </h:inputText>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Product Desc"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{productManagedBean.productDesc}" required="true">                            
                    </h:inputText>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Product Date"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{productManagedBean.purchaseDate}" required="true">  
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>  
                    </h:inputText>

                    <h:commandLink value="Update" action="index" actionListener="#{productController.update(productManagedBean)}" />

                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </fcore:view>
    </center>
</h:body>
```

here is web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
 <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score -2):

The ProductManagedBean must be SessionScop to load the values on the editProduct.xhtml.

Comment: I tried changing into SessionScope but still the values are not displayed on the form.  The result is as same as previous i.e. empty form only gets loaded.